# Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Even though I deleted that part

Tags: python, django

I'm implementing a search functionality in my Meme List View:

```
class MemeListView(ListView):
    model = Meme
    paginate_by = 100
    ordering = ['-created_at']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        search_value = self.request.GET.get("search", False)
        if search_value:
            memes = Q(title__icontains=search_value)
            objects = Meme.objects.filter(memes).select_related().distinct().order_by('-created_at')[:10]
            context['meme_list'] = objects
            context['search'] = search_value


        return context
```

The only part of template that contains logout(I deleted it and restarted the server. The error is still there)

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
         <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href='{% url 'site:logout' %}'>Logout</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
```

Now the issue is only if I search for a thing that has 0 results. If I search and find something everything works fine. Any Idea what is going on?

Edit:
added urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                  path('', include('mysite.urls')),
                  path('', include('memes.urls')),
                  path('', MemeListView.as_view(), name='all'),

              ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', CreateUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

]
```

entire traceback:

```
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 47, in inner
                response = await sync_to_async(response_for_exception, thread_sensitive=False)(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 204, in _get_response
                response = response.render() …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 105, in render
            self.content = self.rendered_content …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py, line 83, in rendered_content
        return template.render(context, self._request) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py, line 61, in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 170, in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 150, in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 162, in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py, line 62, in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 312, in render
                return nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 938, in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py, line 905, in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py, line 446, in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py, line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/home/cisco/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
```

```
Error during template rendering
In template /home/cisco/PycharmProjects/memesite/mysite/templates/base.html, error at line 39

Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
29                <li class="nav-item">
30                <a class="nav-link" href='{% url 'site:register' %}'>Register</a>
31            {% endif %}
32        </li>
33      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
34           <li class="nav-item">
35          <a class="nav-link" href='{% url 'site:logout' %}'>Logout</a>
36        </li>
37        {% endif %}
38      </ul>
39      <form class=" my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex flex-row-reverse" method="GET" action="{% url 'memes:all' %}" >
40          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
41        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
42      </form>
43    </div>
```

Comment: where is urls.py?

Comment: I added urls.py as you requested, I didn't think it was necessary

Comment: I don't see an entry in urls.py that has `name='logout'`

Comment: My bad, I stated the issue incorectly and also didn't provide the right urls. I edited it and now it show logout. However it doesn't matter as it works if search can find any result and it works for other urls like login or register

Comment: @HubertBudny have you added `app_name = 'site'` to your included urls.py? Are you sure you have configured the prefix and it shouldn't be `{% url 'logout' %}` without `site:`?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am sure about it. Also the site works fine unless I search a phrase that has 0 results(which is the main riddle). The error stays the same even after I erase the logout part of template and restart the server.

Comment: Can you add the entire traceback to your question? Sounds like it may not be raised by that particular part of your template

Comment: Added entire traceback

Answer (score -1):

After losing hope I tried this:

```
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        search_value = self.request.GET.get("search", False)
        if search_value:
            memes = Q(title__icontains=search_value)
            objects = Meme.objects.filter(memes).select_related().distinct().order_by('-created_at')[:10]
#difference from here
            if len(objects)>0:
                context['meme_list'] = objects
                context['search'] = search_value
            else:
                context['meme_list'] = False


        return context
```

And it solved the issue. It seems the problem was that if no memes were found there was a meme_list with no objects in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).